# Login a user programmatically via JAAS

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jaas

I'm trying to run code within JBoss Container under a different authentication by programatically logging in a user like that (stripped exception handling):

```
LoginContext ctx = ctx = 
    new LoginContext("MyLoginSchema", 
        new UsernamePasswordCallbackHandler("newuser", "")
    );
ctx.login();

Subject.doAs(ctx.getSubject(), new PrivilegedAction<T>() {
    @Override
    public T run() {
        Subject.getSubject(AccessController.getContext());
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        EJBContext sctxLookup = (EJBContext) ic.lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");
        Principal principal = sctxLookup.getCallerPrincipal();
    }           
});
```

Login of `newuser` works (Call of `LoginModule` was successful) but `Subject.doAs()` doesn't associate the new Subject with the `EJBContext`. The code in the `run()`-Method still fetches the old user's principal from `EJBContext`.

I tested another method of retrieving the logged in user but same behavior here:

```
Subject caller = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which `LoginModule` do you use now? In JBoss 6.1 you had to use `ClientLoginModule` to authenticate in container.

Comment: Yes! That's the point. I added ClientLoginModule and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this is currently not supported by JBoss AS 7.1. See [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/750783#thread-message-750777)

**Edit**

What I wrote here is wrong, the thread only applies to client side login (outside of a JBoss).

Comment: it is supported. See answer above.

Comment: Ah, yes, it's sever side login, my bad.

Comment: No, the Answer is korrect. My code works with ClientLoginmodule in the LoginModule-stack.