# How can I change user principal during an EJB/MDB invocation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, ejb, jaas

I have an application in which some operations are performed by MDB. These MDB all use a `@RunAs(SYSTEM)` annotation to mark them as system elements.

One of these MDB has to run some code which is protecetd through `@RolesAllowed(WORKSPACE)`, which the `SYSTEM` role doesn't have, obviously, but which the `user` (a human being, mind you) that started the process has.

So, my question is quite simple : is there any way (through asynchronous invocation, as an example) to have my MDB to change its principal to be my `user` instead of `SYSTEM` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Mike Braun answer suggest, this is **not** possible according to JavaEE specifications.

And that is unfortunate. But, what is a little less unfortunate is that there is some code to do that kind of things (application-server specific), hidden in that application server implementation of `@RunAs`. In Glassfish, that particular code is in the [`com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/glassfish/security/security/3.1.1/security-3.1.1-sources.jar!/com/sun/enterprise/security/auth/login/LoginContextDriver.java?format=ok) class, and particularly in its `LoginContextDriver#loginPrincipal` method.

So, to have one part of code using a specific principal, I defined an interface

```
public interface Sudoer {
    public <Result> Result sudo(String user, SudoOperation<Result> operation);
}
```

which I implemented for Glassfish as so :

```
public class GlassfishSudoer implements Sudoer {
    @Override
    public <Result> Result sudo(String user, SudoOperation<Result> operation) {
        try {
            LoginContextDriver.loginPrincipal(user, "autocat");
            return operation.perform();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UnableToSudoException(e);
        } finally {
            LoginContextDriver.logout();
        }
    }
}
```

And when using it, the part which wants to have some code "sudoed" only has to provide an implementation of the SudoOperation, like

```
    component.sudo(userLogin, new SudoOperation<Void>() {
        public Void perform() {
            /* do some sudoed code */
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Advantage of this method is that, provided the given application server has some code to handle `@RunAs`, you can use that code to implement your own sudoer (I'm thinking about extracting that into a sudo-ejb library ...).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that *SYSTEM* is a role, while with *user* you really mean the user who send eg a JMS message to say a queue the MDB is listening on?

If you want to set a Principal with the exact roles as that user (basically propagate the user's security context or do a container login from within the MDB), then this is unfortunately not possible. There is a request to standardize container logins in EJB (see EJB spec JIRA), but that won't help you now.

A workaround for this could be a JAX-RS resource, which can use the Servlet API to trigger a login of any given user. You have to be careful here that you don't create a gaping security leak (eg by allowing login by username only), but it's an option.

If you only need the role *WORKSPACE*, then can't you simply use a second @RunAs?

Comment: can you pleas provide an example for this approach? i know jax rs, but how to login via servlet api?

Comment: @dermoritz use HttpServletRequest.authenticate() or HttpServletRequest.login()

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
[A recent question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779566/login-a-user-programmatically-via-jaas)

Its a more generic approach. Working in JBoss for me.